# In the figure two regular pentagons are shown. Calculate "x".

Tags: geometry

For reference:
In the figure two regular pentagons are shown. Calculate "x".

[image]

My progress..I marked the angles I found but I couldn't find the equation to solve

$a_i = \frac{180(5-2)}{5}=108^o\\ \triangle BCG (isosceles) \therefore \measuredangle CGB = 36^o$

If we find $\measuredangle DCF$ the problem is solved because $\measuredangle DJF$ is half of $\measuredangle DCF$

[image]

Comment: Usually, the imperative is "find $x$", but unfortunately, i even could not find it in the picture. So calculating it is a big problem... Please use the many letters from the pictures to tell us what is $x$... (It may be an angle, since for segments we also need a unit for the lengths...) Also, it would be nice to start defining points in some order (even if the original source ignores such annoying steps, where the author has to work), just to make sure that e.g. the colinearity of $D,E,F,I$ is part of the **given** data. Could you please edit the question... ?!

Comment: @dan_fulea..sorry for my carelessness..already corrected

Comment: Do you mean to find the angle $DJF$? Clearly, $DCF = \pi/5$, although I don't why you say that $DJF$ is half of this value? Indeed, by inspection, $DJF$ must be larger.

Comment: @Enforce..you're right...I confused it with another property...but it doesn't apply to the case

Comment: @Enforce ..the answer: $ 72^o$

Comment: @Jitendra Singh  It's exactly, what I wrote.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg well ya after reading the question I thought a similar method as you Michael but since you have written the answer I wrote it as a comment

Comment: is EI a straight line?

Comment: Doug M ..yes, it's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $ \angle CFI = 108^\circ $, so $ \angle CDF = \angle DFC = 180^\circ - 108^\circ = 72 $.

Therefore, $ \angle FCD = 180 - 2 \cdot 72^\circ = 36^\circ $.

Then $ \angle GCD = 108^\circ + 36^\circ = 144^\circ $.

Since $ \triangle GCD $ is isosceles, $ \angle CDG = \frac{180^\circ - 144^\circ}{2} = 18^\circ $.

Then $ \angle DFJ = \angle JDF = 72^\circ - 18^\circ = 54^\circ $.

We can then conclude that $ x = 180^\circ - 2 \cdot 54^\circ = 72^\circ $.

Answer (score 2):

$\angle{FDC} = \angle{DFC} = 180 - 108 = 72$

Therefore, $\angle{DCF} = 180 - 72 \times 2 = 36$

Therefore, $\angle{DCG} = 36 + 108 = 144$

Therefore, $\angle{CDG} = \angle{CGD} = \frac{180 - 144}2 = 18$

Therefore, $\angle{JDF} = 180 - 108 -18 = 54$

Therefore, $x = \angle{DJF} = 180 - 54 \times 2 = 72$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you got the right answer because $$\measuredangle DCE=360^{\circ}-3\cdot108^{\circ}=36^{\circ},$$ which gives $$\measuredangle CDG=18^{\circ}.$$